# auto-detect nested json response of HTTP plugin in datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to call an HTTP GET API using HTTP batch source plugin in data fusion. The response of the API is a complex dynamic nested json because of which I cannot manually specify the output schema. Is there anyway to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the CDAP documentation for [*Parsing nested JSON*](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/developer-manual/pipelines/plugins/transforms/jsonparser-transform.html#parsing-nested-json) events, you might find that this plugin purely uses [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library for JSON key-values extractions with significant expressions usage, that could be reasonable for dynamic key JSON parsing:

> The "root member object" for parsing any JSON is referred to as $,
>   regardless of whether it's an array or an object. It also uses either
>   dot notation or bracket notation for defining the levels of parsing.
>   For example: $.employee.name or $['employee']['name']

You can always refer to the [JSON Path](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/en/user-guide/data-preparation/directives/json-path.html) CDAP directive guidance to get familiar with dedicated functions and operators to manage filtering of the dynamic data.